# Eclipse and SubClipse: How to deploy my own package with svn to a TomCat server?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subclipse

I'm using SubClipse for Eclipse for my project. 
And in this project I've added my own package "com.mytestpkg.www"

I then use TortoiseSVN to deploy my project on the TomCat server where the project is running, because i the easily can update the site with "SVN Update".

But using this method I always have to manually update my package by copying it from my Eclipse workspace build path to the WEB-INF folder classes/com/mytestpkg/www.

Is there a way to make Subclipse/SVN update this file directly with the other files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you do this a more conventional way; e.g.

- get Eclipse to create and deploy a WAR file
- use Ant or Maven to build the WAR file and deploy it by hand.  (The Maven way of building WAR files is really slick!)

Doing a checkout into a Tomcat server's webapps directory is ... weird.  And you've got the problem of stopping the world seeing the `.svn` directories.

Comment: The "by hand" step can be eliminated as well, e.g. the sample ant build.xml here includes a deploy target; http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/appdev/build.xml.txt